# React native : images generating network error

Tags: javascript, node.js, reactjs, react-native, multer

When sending images to a react-native application, some image returns a Network Error.

I can not find the solution, because other image is sent perfectly.
If anyone would have a solution for this problem!

##### React native application

```js
let data = new FormData()
data.append('file', {
    name: picture.uri.split('/').pop(),
    type: picture.type,
    uri: picture.uri
})
```

```js
await axios.post(URL, data, {
    headers: {
        'Accept': 'application/json',
        'Content-Type': `multipart/form-data;boundary='--${Date.now()}--'`
    }
}).catch(err => console.log('ERROR', err))
```

##### NodeJS server

```js
const storage = multer.diskStorage({
    destination(req, file, cb) {
        console.log("destination", file)
        cb(null, '../../cloud/channels/')
    },
    filename(req, file, cb) {
        cb(null, Date.now() + path.extname(file.originalname))
    }
})

const upload = multer({
    storage,
    limits: {
        fileSize: 1024 * 1024 * 20
    }
})
```

```js
app.post('/', upload.single('file'),(req: Request, res: Response) => {
    console.log('FILE', req.file)

    return res.status(200).json({
        result: 'ok'
    })
})
```

thanks in advance

Comment: Why is the title in French? Please translate it to English as the rest of the post.

Comment: @kiner_shah I made a mistake, but when I put the title in English, it says: "Title cannot contain ..." 

Comment: For your problem, you should check the image names and their paths. Also, what is the HTTP code do you get for those requests?

Comment: Maybe the Content-Type header casues the error. Can you try to change it to         'Content-Type': 'multipart/form-data'

Comment: @kiner_shah The problem is that with some images not working and others not

Comment: @Mees If I remove the boundary parameter it gives me a missing boundary error

Comment: And I noticed that it doesn't send to the server, like the error came from before sending the image.

Comment: I lowered the **quality** of the **ImagePicker library** and **compress** of the **ImageManipulator** library to **0.6** instead of **1** and it seems to work! Could it be a weight issue?